# How To Save My Symfony 2 Collection?

Tags: jquery, symfony

I think I am a little confused has to how Symfony 2 deals with this and I am now sorta suck on how to save the collection.

I an using Symfony 2.7.10

I have a form, which I have copied, so two form types, the second setup has a collection, which I can add to the form with JQuery.

My Form Code: - This is the form I render

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
      $builder
        ->add('input1', 'text', ['label' => 'xxxx:'])
        ->add('input2', 'text', ['label' => 'xxxx:'])
        ->add('inputcol', 'collection', [
                                        'type' => new AddInputsType(),
                                        'allow_add' => true,
                                        'allow_delete' => true,
                                        'prototype' => true,
                                        'label' => false,
                                        'mapped' => false
                                        ]);
}
```

This is the form for the `inputcol` collection

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('input1', 'test', ['label' => 'Other1:'])
        ->add('input2', 'text', ['label' => 'Other2:']);
}
```

This is the Form being rendered in my template

```
{{ form_start(FormTest) }}

     <span id="testMe" data-count="1" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(FormTest.inputcol.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        {% for emailField in FormTest.inputcol %}
            {{ form_errors(emailField) }}
            {{ form_widget(emailField) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </span>

    <span class="ContentHere"></span>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="addNew" class="btn">ADD</div>
    </div>

{{ form_end(FormTest) }}
```

That code, I think, was coded from the Symfony 2 docs.

And this is my JQuery code

```
var testAJAX = function() {
  $('#addNew').on('click', function() {
    var GetDataCount = parseInt( $('#testMe').attr('data-count') );
    var emailList = $('#testMe');
    var newWidget = emailList.attr('data-prototype');

        newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, GetDataCount);

    var newCount = GetDataCount + 1;
    $('#testMe').attr('data-count', newCount);

    var newLi = $('.ContentHere').append(newWidget);
  });
};

testAJAX();
```

Again, this I think also come from the docs but I have edited to count the loop with a `data-count` tag. I did that mainly because this code is being run with a Grunt Task, which would not like the Twig template code.

This all seems to work without any problems, however I am know a little git confused on how to get this data to save with my entities.

This is how my controller code looks,

```
public function AdminHomeAction(Request $MyRequest) {

    $GetEn = new EntityHere();
    $ActionURL = $this->generateUrl('dashboard');
    $Form = $this->createForm(new AddTestType(), $GetEn, ['action' => $ActionURL])
                         ->add('save', 'submit', ['label' => 'SAVE',
                                                  'attr' => ['class' => 'SaveButton'],
                                                 ]);

    $Form->handleRequest($MyRequest);

    if ($Form->isValid()) {
            $test = $MyRequest->get('xxxxx')['xxxxx'];

            dump(  $test );

            dump( $_POST );

            die();
    }

    return $this->render('Bundle:home.html.twig', ['FormTest' => $Form->createView()]);
}
```

Now I know that my JQuery looks like it is working fine (or at lest I think it is). It can add has many inputs has I want and I can access that data with both the `$_POST` and Symfony 2 `Request`.

However when I try to access the Entity, it is always empty? How do I bind the data from my post data back to the entity? or have I done something wrong?

All help most welcome

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However when I try to access the Entity, it is always empty? How do I
>   bind the data from my post data back to the entity? or have I done
>   something wrong?

When 'mapped' => false then value from the request is not bounded with the entity

Comment: ok, but if I take that off, how does that work? I am guesting I have to set up a getter and setter for collection so that it gets mapped right? Thanks!

Comment: Add property to the entity and the use doctrine:generate:entities command to generate methods.

Comment: Thanks mate, I give that a go when I can! Many thanks

Comment: That did work, re did some of my code and mapped it out right